# Flutter: How to place the sign in and sign out functions at different pages of the app?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I am currently creating an account-based mobile app for my school project using Firebase authentication.

Currently, the only way to sign out a user is a case-switch basis between the `LoginPage` and the `HomePage` - which is to say that the sign out function must be in the `HomePage` or else there would be a null exception.

Is there any way to place the sign out button on another page of the app (e.g. profile page)?

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    switch (authStatus) {
        case AuthStatus.notSignedIn: 
            return new LoginPage(
                auth: widget.auth,
                onSignedIn: _signedIn,
            );
        case AuthStatus.signedIn:
            return new HomePage(
                auth: widget.auth,
                onSignedOut: _signedOut,
            );
    }
}
```

Comment: is this _signedOut a bool? if it is then just change that to false and you are signOut

Comment: _signedOut is a function that sets the state of the user to notSignedIn. Vice versa for _signedIn.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a file called `auth.dart`

```
//auth.dart

import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
```

In your `profile.dart` you could import `auth.dart` so that you can make use of the `auth` instance to signout.

```
//profile.dart
import 'auth.dart';

...

auth.signOut();
```

Similarly you could make use of the `auth` elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method to logout your user from firebase, even if they logged in using facebook, google or any other auth provider.

```
Future<void> signOut() async {
    //create an instance you your firebase auth.
    final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

    //return this future to the place you called it.
    return _firebaseAuth.signOut().whenComplete(() {
      Navigator.pop(context);
      print("SignOut Done");
    }).catchError((error) {
      print("error in signout $error");
    });
  }
```